# Rails Simple_form - edit + show page duplicating nested form every time Its clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms

I am working on a basic web app, and one of the requirements is a Profile page with a nested form. The nested form is a model called experience, which basically asks the user if they had previous work experience or not and asking for basic information regarding their work experience. This nested form needs to be able to to be duplicated so the user can add as many as they need, which is why im using the nested_form gem.

The issue im having is that the form itself seems to get ducplicated everytime i click on the edit button, and after a few times i end up with the nested form being repeated 5 or 6 times with no way of removing them (despite adding the remove link that comes with the nested_form gem). Im not sure what the issue is, but im assuming its either with my controller or the way i set up my nested form in the _form page. Please help!

My code:-

my form:

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for(@profile) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

     .
     .
     .

    <%= f.input :work_experience, collection: ['No', 'Yes'], label: 'Previous Work Experience?', as: :radio_buttons, :include_blank => false %>
   </div>
  </div>


    <%= f.simple_fields_for :experiences do |builder| %>
        <%= builder.input :company %>
    <%= builder.input :period_of_employment, label: 'Period of Employement:', as: :date, start_year: Date.today.year - 50, end_year: Date.today.year, order: [:day, :month, :year], input_html: { class: 'inline-date' } %>
    <%= builder.input :title, label: 'Job Title' %>
    <%= builder.link_to_remove "Remove" %>

      <% end %>
   <%= f.link_to_add "Add another", :experiences %>


    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Profile Controller

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @profiles = Profile.all
    respond_with(@profiles)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@profile)
  end

  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
    @profile.experiences.build
    respond_with(@profile)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
    @profile.user_id = current_user.id
    @profile.save
    respond_with(@profile)
  end

  def update
    @profile.update(profile_params)
    respond_with(@profile)
  end

  def destroy
    @profile.destroy
    respond_with(@profile)
  end

  private
    def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    end

    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:name, :civil, :date_of_employment, :mobile, :work_email, :personal_email, :internal_no, :nationality, :gender, :academic_degree, :major, :work_experience, experiences_attributes: [:company, :period_of_employment, :title])
    end
end
```

Experience Controller:

```
class ExperiencesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_experience, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @experiences = Experience.all
    respond_with(@experiences)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@experience)
  end

  def new
    @experience = Experience.new
    respond_with(@experience)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @experience = Experience.new(experience_params)
    @experience.save
    respond_with(@experience)
  end

  def update
    @experience.update(experience_params)
    respond_with(@experience)
  end

  def destroy
    @experience.destroy
    respond_with(@experience)
  end

  private
    def set_experience
      @experience = Experience.find(params[:id])
    end

    def experience_params
      params.require(:experience).permit(:company, :period_of_employment, :title)
    end
end
```

Profile Model:

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

```
    belongs_to :users
    has_many :experiences

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :experiences, allow_destroy: true


end
```

Experience Model:

```
class Experience < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :profile 

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, currently the `nested_form` is generating ***new records*** when you click on ***edit*** instead of ***updating*** the existing ones.

You need to pass `:id` in your `profile_params` for the ***update*** to work.

```
def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:id, :name, :civil, :date_of_employment, :mobile, :work_email, :personal_email, :internal_no, :nationality, :gender, :academic_degree, :major, :work_experience, experiences_attributes: [:id, :company, :period_of_employment, :title])
end
```

***Update***

You need to pass `:_destroy` for the ***Delete*** to work.

```
def profile_params
   params.require(:profile).permit(:id, :name, :civil, :date_of_employment, :mobile, :work_email, :personal_email, :internal_no, :nationality, :gender, :academic_degree, :major, :work_experience, experiences_attributes: [:id, :company, :period_of_employment, :title, :_destroy])
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried adding id but still having the same issue. every time i click on edit, there is another duplication of the nested form in main form. What I would is that if the nested_form doesnt appear at all unless the user clicks on a "add experience" link provided within the form. how can I make that happen?

Comment: ok I just double checked and it seems adding the "id" seems to have corrected the duplication issue. the only issue im having now is with deleting the exisiitng records after they are added to the form. The delete link doesnt seem to be working for some reason. Would you know how to fix this?